# what is the difference between haula and hilala?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, arabic

Salam,
What is the difference between haula (as in La haula wa la...) and hilal (as in hilalahuma nahara)? Do they come from the same root word?

Comment: Questions on Arabic langauge are off-topic. Note that the first is hawla حول and the second is khilala خلال they are obviously not related neither in the roots nor the meaning.